# Почему возникает ошибка KeyError: 0

Tags: python, массивы, словари

```
n = int(input())
x=[]
a={}
def f(x):
   return x+1
for i in range(n):
    x.append(int(input()))
    if x[i] not in a.keys():
        a.update({x[i]:f(x[i])})
        print(a[i])
    else:
        print(a[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас в `a[i]` `i` - это не значение введенное юзером, а его индекс в списке `x`.

Например на первой итерации я введу число 10, оно попадет на 0 индекс в списке `x`.
Потом вы кладете число на индексе 0 в ваш словарь, тем самым имеем `{10: ...}`.
Как видите ключ у нас 10 а не 0, а вы пытаетесь вытащить 0.

Решение: замените `a[i]` на `a[x[i]]`.

Answer (score -1):

У словаря `a` нет ключа `i`, поэтому и возникает эта ошибка.

Если вводить последовательно `0, 1, 2, ...,n-1`, то ошибок не будет.

Answer (score -1):

Перемудрил сильно в for:
Можно сделать так:

```
for i in range(n):
    x.append(int(input()))
    if x[i] not in a.keys():
        a[i] = f(x[i])
    print(a[i])
```

Comment: Бесполезный и неправильный ответ, оно не работает так как ожидает автор